# c++ error on start 0xc0000017 (process exited with code -1073741801) with big heap size

Tags: c++, 64-bit, heap-size

I'm trying to create c++ program in Visual Studio 2019 that can use more than 4Gb of heap size, I created a new "Hello World" solution, selected x64 platform everywhere, and set 4300000000 of Heap Reserve Size in Linker -> System [screen of Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orVC1.png), build succeeded but I can't run program, I'm getting 0xc0000017 error code in separate error window ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRjZe.png)), and "*(process 23616) exited with code -1073741801.*" in console.

With heap size 4200000000 program start and work correctly.

How to create/configure program for using big amount of heap space?

Comment: No images of code, error messages or otherwisde plain text, strictly! Provide a [mcve] as required here, or we consider your problems aren't existent at all.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ my program is "Hello Word", is there anything that could be simpler as example for reproducing?

Comment: *How to create/configure program for using big amount of heap space?* -- There is nothing to configure.  Start from the beginning, not do anything except tell the compiler to build a 64-bit program, and everything will work.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to create c++ program in Visual Studio 2019 that can use more than 4Gb of heap size

Building your program as x64 is enough. You don't need (or want) those other tricks.

Comment: I want to use big arrays that will consume a lot of heap memory, this program is just simple example. The problem is that I can't run program if I set [HEAP option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/heap-set-heap-size?view=msvc-160) more than 4.3 Gb

Comment: You don't need to use the /HEAP option to do that.  Just allocate the memory you need and, subject to resource constraints on your machine, Windows will give it to you.

Comment: @Igor -- The compiler is smart enough to figure this all out.  You're not dealing with a 32-bit application and attempting to use "tricks".  A 64-bit program will work right out-of-the-box.